# Optimized way to add all float elements in an array to every float in another array

Tags: c++, arrays, math, logic

The code I have come up with so far is

```
void sumValues()
{
    float sum = 0;
    int n = NUM_ELEMENTS;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        float x = dataX[i];
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            float y = dataY[j];
            float val = x + y;
            sum += val;
        }
    }
}
```

What I need to know is, how can this code be optimized?

When doing this kind of logic you have to walk all the elements of both lists, so at a minimum it has to be O(n^2) (AFAIK). How can this be improved?

Comment: When I say "add" I mean Mathematically add not array insertion.

Comment: Hint: the answer is a multiple of n

Comment: Aren't you just (very inefficiently) calculating `n*(sum(x)+sum(y))` ?

Comment: You are talking about adding int elements but i see floats that you add. `float val = x + y;`

Comment: This code can (and probably will) be optimised down to a no-op as it doesn't output anything, nor does it change any outside variables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not clear what you're trying to do: the title suggests you want to take all int values in an array A, compute their sum, and add it to each element in an array B. The complexity for that would be O(n).

Your code does not do that: for all (x,y) pairs where x is in A and y in B, it computes x+y and adds it to a total sum. You can actually notice that the final sum will be `n*(Sum(A) + Sum(B))`, which you can also compute in O(n). But I doubt that's what you want to do...

Comment: So are you saying, walk both arrays and calculate their sum. Then just multiply the number of elements by the combined sum of both arrays?

Comment: Yes I am ! That will take time O(n) + O(n) + O(1)

Answer (score 2):

When in doubt, use arithmetic.

You're computing

```
  (x[0] + y[0]) + (x[0] + y[1]]) + ... + (x[0] + y[n-1])
+ (x[1] + y[0]) + (x[1] + y[1]]) + ... + (x[1] + y[n-1])
...
+ (x[n-1] + y[0]) + (x[n-1] + y[1]]) + ... + (x[n-1] + y[n-1])
```

which is

```
  n * x[0] + y[0] + y[1] + ... + y[n-1]
+ n * x[1] + y[0] + y[1] + ... + y[n-1]
...
+ n * x[n-1] + y[0] + y[1] + ... + y[n-1]
```

which is

```
  n * x[0] + sum(y)
+ n * x[1] + sum(y)
...
+ n * x[n-1] + sum(y)
```

which is

```
  n * (x[0] + x[1] + ... + x[n-1]) + n * sum(y)
```

which is

```
n * sum(x) + n * sum(y)
```

or

```
n * (sum(x) + sum(y))
```

This is `O(n + m)`, where `n` and `m` are the sizes of `x` and `y`, respectively.

Comment: I am generating my test-cases to fill the arrays using values between 0 and 100. Using n * (sumX + sumY) works, but when I generate a larger set of data I get the wrong answers.

Comment: @Nick what do you mean by "wrong"? floating point arithmetics is not precise. Also, where do you get your baseline values from? your current algorithm should be perfectly replaceable with `N*(std::accumulate(dataX,dataX+N,0.f)+std::accumulate(dataY,dataY+N,0.f))`

Answer (score 0):

Since sum(x) = X*Y1+X*Y2+...X*YN, then sum(x) = X*(sum(Y)):

```
void sumValues()
{
    float sum = 0;
    int sumOf2ndArray = 0;
    int n = NUM_ELEMENTS;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        sumOf2ndArray += dataY[i];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        float x = dataX[i];
        sum += x * sumOf2ndArray;
    }
}
```